# Generalization of error-correcting codes

Tags: co.combinatorics, it.information-theory, coding-theory, hamming-distance

If you have a binary single-error correcting code with n-bit codewords, then it is the case that taking only a fixed n-1 out of the n bits gives an “approximate” code with the property that, for any given length n-1 bitstring, there are AT MOST TWO possible codewords whose hamming distance restricted to the n-1 used places is <=1.

Example: the classic (7,4) code with three parity check bits on a 4-bit message, if you forget the last bit, gives you at most 2 possible choices for the original codeword.

My question: what if your code is represented in a k-ary alphabet instead of a binary alphabet, but you still want to limit the number of possible codewords within Hamming distance 1 when you are missing one of the k-ary digits to 2, rather than to k?

Are any examples known of k-ary codes like this, where either the maximum or the average number of possible codewords when the last k-ary digit is missing is at most 2?

Addendum: looking at this from the other direction, an example of the problem I am trying to solve is the following: if I am looking at the 64 possible 3-letter words over the alphabet {0,1,2,3}, classical coding theory will tell me the maximum size of a subset of those words which are all Hamming Distance 3 apart, namely 4 (000, 111, 222, 333 for example), but how large a subset can I find such that at most 2 of them (or an average of <=2 of them) are Hamming distance <=1 from any given word?

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is "list decoding": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_decoding . For instance some Reed-Solomon-type codes can be decoded with a size $O(1/\epsilon))$ list up to the distance of the code minus $\epsilon$ (instead of $\lfloor\frac{d}{2}\rfloor$). I think you'll have to look at the references and use Chernoff bounds to know exactly how many errors you can correct exactly in concrete cases. I would have to think about it, i only know some basic things about codes. In your case you're correcting 2 errors (instead of 1) with a size 2 list of codewords.

Comment: I checked better and one cannot list-decode Hamming(7,4) with 2 errors with size 2-list, as for example $w_0=0000011$ is at distance 2 from 4 codewords. But if on a word $w$ you restrict one error to the last bit and another one anywhere else, then (if i checked correctly) you can find only 2 codewords matching $w$ up to such errors. For instance $0000000$ and $1000011$ for $w_0$. You need codes with appropriate symmetry (like cyclic codes) to relate usual list decoding to what you want: some errors restricted to fixed positions. In any case list decoding is surely the right place to begin.

Comment: Also, i quickly looked up whether there were things on such asymmetric distributions of errors, but usually what is called "asymmetric channel" is a channel where the $1\rightarrow 0$ error is more probable than the $0\rightarrow 1$ one -this seems to be a physically realistic assumption.